# What does it mean by enchanting depends on base use in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> If you are mass enchanting your items, weapons offer a greater profit
> per soul gem used. Weapon enchantment prices are calculated by base
> uses; the fewer base uses an enchantment has, the more expensive the
> enchantment will be. The Banish enchantment is by far the most
> profitable weapon enchantment, followed by Absorb Health and Paralyze.

http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects#Notes

What does it mean?

Mean more users or players use this or what?

Answer (score 4):

It's just what it sounds like, the base uses for that type of enchantment.

The number of uses for an enchantment can be changed when applying it to a weapon. You can choose to have fewer, more powerful uses or more, less powerful uses. But even when going for the most powerful effect with the fewest uses, some enchantments will naturally have a higher use count than other, more powerful enchantments.

The term "base uses" here is used to mean the number of uses of the enchantment before the player chooses to make the effect stronger or weaker.